# Conditionally unwrap optional variables

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say we have a variable that is optional string `text`. Is there a way to optionally unwrap this property? In Swift, we can do something like:

```
guard let unwrappedText = text else { return }
```

In our code, we have a lot of these:

```
if (!text) return
```

Which is fine, but later on, the type of `text` is still an optional string so we still have to deal with unwrapping. Ideally we can check for null *and* unwrap the variable at the same time. I might not have the right term for this because I can't seem to find anything online about conditional unwraps for TypeScript.

Comment: How exactly would you use this? Possibly you just want optional chaining `maybeString?.toUpperCase()`. Maybe null coalescing, `??`.

Comment: yeah exactly. instead of always having to unwrap it in future uses (since the `if (!text) return` already handles the case of it being null. coming from swift where optionals are natively built into the language, doing a null check and then a force unwrap seems slightly weird

Comment: It actually does work exactly like you think it should. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUUCmAPKAuRAZygCcYwBzRAH0TBABsGBKRAbwChFEtcA6KHACqABxGYSAYQCGhTGlYB6RTwCe4xBJJwSXAL4cOoSLASIARtJIYc+IqXJVa9Jq07cYwRGgCEvKKwkmFAgJGBcPLYCwmISMnIKiMrI5JgcekA. Do you have a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler is smart enough to know when an optional type like `string | undefined` has been narrowed to an exact type. For example:

```
function foo(data?: string) {  // Here the type of data is string | undefined
    if (!data) return;

    data;  // Here the type of data is string
}
```

You can see this in action on the TypeScript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUATAhlLB+ALkQGcoAnGMAcwEpEBvAKERcRmETQEJtc6yAplBBkwAbkbNWvLBIC+koA

There are also [more explicit options for type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) in Typescript.